# What is the blockchain download size and can i reduce it in some way?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, parity, light-clients

I am currently on a connection with a download cap, and was wondering what the current download size for the whole blockchain was, and if i could reduce this download size to under 2 GB?

I'm currently using parity.

Comment: Disk space requirements for Parity are around 10GB, I suspect the download size is at least 6GB for the chain and another several 100MB for the state if you use warp sync. But would be interesting if someone can come up with more accurate numbers.

Comment: I compiled parity from source on fedora, and parity --help says warp is on by default, but so far i've downloaded over 15 gb, is that normal? I did interrupt the sync a few times, but i assume the sync can just start where it left off?

Comment: You can increase the number of `--snapshot-peers` and try to figure if warp sync finally kicks in.